# Xamarin Dim Page (Master Detail Page)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, master-detail

So for Android when the master page of a master-detail page is shown the master page is covered with a "black dim" view so it is easy to differentiate the two pages with the eye.  In iOS the detail page is not dimmed so it is tougher to differentiate the views.  Is there a way to overlay the details page with a BoxView or Frame that is "black translucent" so it dims the page in similar fashion to Android.  I have tried many different colors and opacities of a box view but they all completely cover the screen and you can't "see through them".  Any ideas?  Or better solutions?  Even if it is a customer renderer for the BoxView that will work.  I just need color ideas/settings to make it see through.

Comment: Why dont you just change the background color of the master page ?

Comment: Thats not the affect i am going for or the color theme of my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample here:
https://github.com/jgold6/XamarinSupportSamples/tree/master/XForms-TestShadingiOSDetailPage

Here's the code in case the link ever breaks:

```
MasterDetailPage mdPage;
Color origContentBgColor;
Color origPageBgColor;

public App()
    {
        mdPage = new MasterDetailPage();
        mdPage.IsPresentedChanged += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
                if (mdPage.IsPresented) {
                    var currentPage = (DetailPage)((NavigationPage)mdPage.Detail).CurrentPage;
                    origPageBgColor = currentPage.BackgroundColor;
                    origContentBgColor = currentPage.Content.BackgroundColor;

                    currentPage.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
                    currentPage.Content.FadeTo(0.5);
                    if (currentPage.Content.BackgroundColor == Color.Default) {
                        currentPage.Content.BackgroundColor = Color.White;

                    }
                }
                else {
                    var currentPage = (DetailPage)((NavigationPage)mdPage.Detail).CurrentPage;
                    currentPage.BackgroundColor = origPageBgColor;
                    currentPage.Content.BackgroundColor = origContentBgColor;
                    currentPage.Content.FadeTo(1.0);
                }


            }
        };
        mdPage.Master = new MasterPage(){Title = "Master Page"};
        mdPage.Detail = new NavigationPage( new DetailPage());

        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = mdPage;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that is nice and it does work, but the only catch is I see it go dark black then it fades to the color I want and it sort of looks like a flicker when that happens.  Do you know of any way to have some type of overlay view  that I can just show/hide quickly that wouldn't require the color and fade transition?

Comment: Hmm, I did not notice that flickering on my end. But you can still use the `mdPage.IsPresentedChanged` event handler to do whatever you want... i.e. add an overlay on to the detail page, but IIRC adding an overlay was problematic for some reason, hence this solution.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up using this code to just fade the opacity and that works ok for me.

Comment: Hey! How do you suppose this could work with TabbedPages instead of ContentPages?

Comment: @Daniel, I guess it's been awhile since you asked, but I just got this working with tabbed pages by using 
`var currentPage = ((ContentPage)((TabbedPage)App.NavigationPage.CurrentPage)).CurrentPage;`

Answer (score -1):

I just changed the order of `FadeTo()` method to be the last command and the dark black effect is gone!

```
await currentPage.Content.FadeTo(0.5);
```